# Решение задачи Python

Tags: python

Нужна подсказка, а не полное решение ибо так далеко не уйдешь.)))

1. Как вывести число столько раз какого его значение (например, число 3 выводится 3 раза)?
2. Как сделать так чтобы число A  выводилось 1 раз, число A + 1 выводилось 2 раза?

Спасибо!)))

Comment: используйте цикл `for`

Comment: Не поняла ответа. Цикл  for  и так использую для вывода диапазона чисел.

Comment: `for i in range(3):print(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 задача:

```
 num1 = int(input())
    num2 = int(input())
    while num1 != num2 + 1:
        for i in range(num1):
            print(num1)
        num1 += 1
```

2 задача:

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
i = 1
while num1 != num2 + 1:
    b = 0
    while b < i:
        print(num1)
        b += 1
    num1 += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: не называйте переменные такими именами

Comment: Условие задачи полностью: № 1. #Даны 2 целых числа А и В (А < B).
# Напечатать все числа в этом диапазоне от А до В включительно;
# при этом каждое число должно выводиться столько раз, каково его значение (например, число 3 выводится 3 раза).

Comment: №2.#Даны 2 целых числа А и В (А < B). Напечатать все числа в этом диапазоне от А до В включительно;
# при этом число A должно выводиться 1 раз, число A + 1 должно выводиться 2 раза и т. д.

Comment: @ДарьяФрацман добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: я переписал код под задачу 1

Comment: добавил код для второй задачи